Printing and previewing PDF via Print document adapter - Print Preview Doesn't appear correct and missing information and dosn't Match Output
when try to print a pdf file via print document adapter and print manger , pdf dosn't appears fully correct , threr is missing data in the file (the output file is correct one)
here is the image in preivew mode
the full data of pdf after downloading
here is the sample code i use
@Override
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes printAttributes, PrintAttributes printAttributes1, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback layoutResultCallback, Bundle bundle) {
    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
        layoutResultCallback.onLayoutCancelled();
    }
    else {
        PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder=
                new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Contract");
        builder.setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                .setPageCount(PrintDocumentInfo.PAGE_COUNT_UNKNOWN)
                .build();
        layoutResultCallback.onLayoutFinished(builder.build(),
                !printAttributes1.equals(printAttributes));
    }
}

@Override
public void onWrite(PageRange[] pageRanges, ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback writeResultCallback) {

    InputStream in=null;
    OutputStream out=null;
    try {
        File file = new File(pathName);
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        out=new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

        byte[] buf=new byte[16384];
        int size;

        while ((size=in.read(buf)) >= 0
                && !cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            out.write(buf, 0, size);
        }

        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            writeResultCallback.onWriteCancelled();
        }
        else {
            writeResultCallback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[] { PageRange.ALL_PAGES });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        writeResultCallback.onWriteFailed(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("ErrorInWriting" , e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ErrorInFinally" , e.getMessage());
        }
    }`

i tired everything and there is no solution also

Android's print-preview capabilities are not designed to print arbitrary PDFs. They are designed to display things that you created in Android, such as by drawing to a Canvas.

when i try to print the same pdf file in adobe acrobat pdf reader it looks the same as the pdf in preview mode will all data exist , is there anyway to fix that issue ?
